# A clear path to a simulated pr2 grasping demo?

Tags: ros, object-manipulation, pr2-simulator, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've been futzing with the pr2 pick-and-place demo(s) to no avail. There is more than one tutorial:

1. http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/Tutorials/The%20Pick%20and%20Place%20Autonomous%20Demo
2. http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/SimpleGraspingDemo

I've managed to whittle the errors yielded by running (1) down to the following:

"
Database connection failed with error message: could not translate host name "wgs36" to address: Name or service not known

ObjectsDatabaseNode: failed to open model database on host wgs36, port 5432, user willow with password willow, database household_objects. Unable to do grasp planning on database recognized objects. Exiting.
"

and...

"
Error Loading Joint[r_gripper_r_screw_screw_joint]
Error: [/tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-simulator-gazebo-1.2.8/debian/ros-diamondback-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Model.cc:1278]
/tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-simulator-gazebo-1.2.8/debian/ros-diamondback-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Model.cc:923 : Exception: Uknown joint[screw]
"

Has anyone had similar trouble with running the simulated version of these demos? Solutions? Is there a simpler starting point for testing out the object_manipulation stack?

Thanks,
Sean

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10631/a-clear-path-to-a-simulated-pr2-grasping-demo?/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2011-07-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-07-21**:
FYI, running (2) creates a table, object on the table, a PR2 without arms, and a bunch of TF_NAN_INPUT errors. I decided to stick with (1) going forward.

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-07-21**:
I don't exactly know the proper method for "continuing a thread" in ROS Answers, as my next question pertains to the same subject. Both answers below are correct and have helped me thus far. Tutorial (1) runs without throwing errors, but it doesn't spawn a table or an object. Thoughts?

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-07-18**:
I edited the post after hsiao's post because the first error was cut out due to some misplaced brackets. Any insight on the object database error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first step will be to download and install the database locally on your computer. The tutorial is here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/household_objects_database

There should also be an option to use the database remotely on a Willow Garage server, but unfortunately that is not working for diamondback at the moment...

After that, you would edit the pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch file to match your local installation of the database, such as server address, user name, password, etc.

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-07-21**:
Thanks. I followed the instructions and was able to successfully connect to and access a local household_objects database.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The gripper screw joint was added about a month ago to unstable; you can check out gazebo from unstable now to get it, but I would advise waiting until electric is officially released a month from now if you're not in a hurry, since things are still changing pretty fast every day while the release is imminent.

---

Originally posted by [hsiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/142/hsiao/) with karma: 741 on 2011-07-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2011-07-21**:
Thanks. I found one of my packages was, indeed, a trunk version rather than a diamondback-tagged version.